# Как избежать ошибки "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида." при сохранении изображения?

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения, gdi+

При сохранении измененного изображения получаю ошибку:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: "В GDI+ возникла ошибка общего вида."

Код :

```
static void Edit(string x)
{
    Image a = Image.FromFile("Test.jpg"); //получаем исходное изображение из файла
    Graphics part2 = Graphics.FromImage(a); //получаем его часть
    part2.DrawString(x,
        new System.Drawing.Font("Xenia Font", 15, FontStyle.Bold),
        new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke),
        new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 340), //22
        new StringFormat(new StringFormat())); // наносим на эту часть текст с параметрами

    a.Save("Test2.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);//записываем получающееся изображение в файл
}
```

Нужно чтобы при первом вызове создавался файл с измененным изображением, при последующих - перезаписывался. Пробовал сохранять в другие места и без указания формата:

```
a.Save(@"D:\\Test2.jpg");
a.Save("Test2.jpg");
```

В итоге такая же ошибка. Чем это может быть вызвано?

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка может возникнуть в том случае, если пытаться сохранять в уже открытый файл. То есть ресурс "Test2.jpg" ранее был открыт и не освобождён.

Так что ищите в своём коде, где у вас ещё используется "Test2.jpg" (и не освобождается при этом).

---

У вас не используются `Dispose`/`using`. Покажу, как должен выглядеть правильный код. Заодно поправил нейминг.

```
static void Edit(string text)
{
    using (var image = Image.FromFile("Test.jpg"))
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    using (var font = new Font("Xenia Font", 15, FontStyle.Bold))
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke))
    using (var stringFormat = new StringFormat())
    {
        graphics.DrawString(
            text,
            font,
            brush,
            new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 340),
            stringFormat
        );

        image.Save("Test2.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Вообще, `stringFormat` вполне можно убрать, т. к. ему не задаются параметры, отличные от дефолтных.

`RectangleF` не является `disposable`, поэтому его не нужно заключать в `using`.

Также неясно, зачем метод сделан статическим.